# Java compare and swap semantics and performance

Tags: java, performance, concurrency, jvm, compare-and-swap

What is the semantics of compare and swap in Java? Namely, does the compare and swap method of an `AtomicInteger` just guarantee ordered access between different threads to the particular memory location of the atomic integer instance, or does it guarantee ordered access to all the locations in memory, i.e. it acts as if it were a volatile (a memory fence).

From the [docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html):

- `weakCompareAndSet` atomically reads and conditionally writes a variable but does not create any happens-before orderings, so provides no guarantees with respect to previous or subsequent reads and writes of any variables other than the target of the `weakCompareAndSet`.
- `compareAndSet` and all other read-and-update operations such as `getAndIncrement` have the memory effects of both reading and writing volatile variables.

It's apparent from the API documentation that `compareAndSet` acts as if it were a volatile variable. However, `weakCompareAndSet` is supposed to just change its specific memory location. Thus, if that memory location is exclusive to the cache of a single processor, `weakCompareAndSet` is supposed to be much faster than the regular `compareAndSet`.

I'm asking this because I've benchmarked the following methods by running `threadnum` different threads, varying `threadnum` from 1 to 8, and having `totalwork=1e9` (the code is written in Scala, a statically compiled JVM language, but both its meaning and bytecode translation are isomorphic to that of Java in this case - this short snippets should be clear):

```scala
val atomic_cnt = new AtomicInteger(0)
val atomic_tlocal_cnt = new java.lang.ThreadLocal[AtomicInteger] {
  override def initialValue = new AtomicInteger(0)
}

def loop_atomic_tlocal_cas = {
  var i = 0
  val until = totalwork / threadnum
  val acnt = atomic_tlocal_cnt.get
  while (i < until) {
    i += 1
    acnt.compareAndSet(i - 1, i)
  }
  acnt.get + i
}

def loop_atomic_weakcas = {
  var i = 0
  val until = totalwork / threadnum
  val acnt = atomic_cnt
  while (i < until) {
    i += 1
    acnt.weakCompareAndSet(i - 1, i)
  }
  acnt.get + i
}

def loop_atomic_tlocal_weakcas = {
  var i = 0
  val until = totalwork / threadnum
  val acnt = atomic_tlocal_cnt.get
  while (i < until) {
    i += 1
    acnt.weakCompareAndSet(i - 1, i)
  }
  acnt.get + i
}
```

on an AMD with 4 dual 2.8 GHz cores, and a 2.67 GHz 4-core i7  processor. The JVM is Sun Server Hotspot JVM 1.6. The results show no performance difference.

## Specs: AMD 8220 4x dual-core @ 2.8 GHz

#### Test name:   loop_atomic_tlocal_cas

- Thread num.: 1

Run times:  (showing last 3)
7504.562     7502.817     7504.626    (avg = 7415.637     min = 7147.628     max = 7504.886    )

- Thread num.: 2

Run times:  (showing last 3)
3751.553     3752.589     3751.519    (avg = 3713.5513    min = 3574.708     max = 3752.949    )

- Thread num.: 4

Run times:  (showing last 3)
1890.055     1889.813     1890.047  (avg = 2065.7207    min = 1804.652     max = 3755.852    )

- Thread num.: 8

Run times:  (showing last 3)
960.12      989.453      970.842     (avg = 1058.8776    min = 940.492      max = 1893.127    )

---

#### Test name:   loop_atomic_weakcas

- Thread num.: 1

Run times:  (showing last 3)
7325.425     7057.03      7325.407    (avg = 7231.8682    min = 7057.03      max = 7325.45     )

- Thread num.: 2

Run times:  (showing last 3)
3663.21      3665.838     3533.406    (avg = 3607.2149    min = 3529.177     max = 3665.838    )

- Thread num.: 4

Run times:  (showing last 3)
3664.163     1831.979     1835.07     (avg = 2014.2086    min = 1797.997     max = 3664.163    )

- Thread num.: 8

Run times:  (showing last 3)
940.504      928.467      921.376     (avg = 943.665      min = 919.985      max = 997.681     )

---

#### Test name:   loop_atomic_tlocal_weakcas

- Thread num.: 1

Run times:  (showing last 3)
7502.876     7502.857     7502.933    (avg = 7414.8132    min = 7145.869     max = 7502.933    )

- Thread num.: 2

Run times:  (showing last 3)
3752.623     3751.53      3752.434    (avg = 3710.1782    min = 3574.398     max = 3752.623    )

- Thread num.: 4

Run times:  (showing last 3)
1876.723     1881.069     1876.538    (avg = 4110.4221    min = 1804.62      max = 12467.351   )

- Thread num.: 8

Run times:  (showing last 3)
959.329      1010.53      969.767     (avg = 1072.8444    min = 959.329      max = 1880.049    )

## Specs: Intel i7 quad-core @ 2.67 GHz

#### Test name:   loop_atomic_tlocal_cas

- Thread num.: 1

Run times:  (showing last 3)
8138.3175    8130.0044    8130.1535   (avg = 8119.2888    min = 8049.6497    max = 8150.1950   )

- Thread num.: 2

Run times:  (showing last 3)
4067.7399    4067.5403    4068.3747   (avg = 4059.6344    min = 4026.2739    max = 4068.5455   )

- Thread num.: 4

Run times:  (showing last 3)
2033.4389    2033.2695    2033.2918   (avg = 2030.5825    min = 2017.6880    max = 2035.0352   )

---

#### Test name:   loop_atomic_weakcas

- Thread num.: 1

Run times:  (showing last 3)
8130.5620    8129.9963    8132.3382   (avg = 8114.0052    min = 8042.0742    max = 8132.8542   )

- Thread num.: 2

Run times:  (showing last 3)
4066.9559    4067.0414    4067.2080   (avg = 4086.0608    min = 4023.6822    max = 4335.1791   )

- Thread num.: 4

Run times:  (showing last 3)
2034.6084    2169.8127    2034.5625   (avg = 2047.7025    min = 2032.8131    max = 2169.8127   )

---

#### Test name:   loop_atomic_tlocal_weakcas

- Thread num.: 1

Run times:  (showing last 3)
8132.5267    8132.0299    8132.2415   (avg = 8114.9328    min = 8043.3674    max = 8134.0418   )

- Thread num.: 2

Run times:  (showing last 3)
4066.5924    4066.5797    4066.6519   (avg = 4059.1911    min = 4025.0703    max = 4066.8547   )

- Thread num.: 4

Run times:  (showing last 3)
2033.2614    2035.5754    2036.9110   (avg = 2033.2958    min = 2023.5082    max = 2038.8750   )

---

While it's possible that thread locals in the example above end up in the same cache lines, it seems to me that there is no observable performance difference between regular CAS and its weak version.

This could mean that, in fact, a weak compare and swap acts as fully fledged memory fence, i.e. acts as if it were a volatile variable.

Question: Is this observation correct? Also, is there a known architecture or Java distribution for which a weak compare and set is actually faster? If not, what is the advantage of using a weak CAS in the first place?

Comment: x86 does not support a non-strongly guaranteed CAS as it has LOCK prefix. So Weak and Standard CAS are the same operation.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

A weak compare and swap *could* act as a full volatile variable, depending on the implementation of the JVM, sure.  In fact, I wouldn't be surprised if on certain architectures it is not possible to implement a weak CAS in a notably more performant way than the normal CAS.  On these architectures, it may well be the case that weak CASes are implemented exactly the same as a full CAS.  Or it might simply be that your JVM has not had much optimisation put into making weak CASes particularly fast, so the *current* implementation just invokes a full CAS because it's quick to implement, and a future version will refine this.

The JLS simply says that a weak CAS does not establish a *happens-before* relationship, so it's simply that there is no **guarantee** that the modification it causes is visible in other threads.  All you get in this case is the guarantee that the compare-and-set operation is atomic, but with no guarantees about the visibility of the (potentially) new value.  That's not the same as guaranteeing that it *won't* be seen, so your tests are consistent with this.

In general, try to avoid making any conclusions about concurrency-related behaviour through experimentation.  There are so many variables to take into account, that if you don't follow what the JLS guarantees to be correct, then your program *could* break at any time (perhaps on a different architecture, perhaps under more aggressive optimisation that's prompted by a slight change in the layout of your code, perhaps under future builds of the JVM that don't exist yet, etc.).  There's **never** a reason to assume you can get away with something that's stated not to be guaranteed, because experiments show that "it works".

Comment: Can you provide the citation from the JLS? All I can find about the semantics of weakCompareAndSet are the javadocs on the method.

Comment: `future version will refine this` it already did this in jdk-9, where `weak` is well... `weak`

Comment: so the memory used by CAS is the main memory (for all threads), right?

Answer (score 33):

The x86 instruction for "atomically compare and swap" is `LOCK CMPXCHG`. This instruction creates a full memory fence.

There is no instruction that does this job without creating a memory fence, so it is very likely that both `compareAndSet` and `weakCompareAndSet` map to `LOCK CMPXCHG` and perform a full memory fence.

But that's for x86, other architectures (including future variants of x86) may do things differently.

Comment: +1 for giving the technical background that supports the observation.

Comment: Just a link to the instruction set reference: http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/

Comment: x86 is strictly ordered so but LL/CS [load linked/store conidional] type of instructions on IBM Power can use weak CAS, Also weak CAS can actually fail even if the preconditions are fine.

Answer (score 7):

`weakCompareAndSwap` is not *guaranteed* to be faster; it's just *permitted* to be faster. You can look at the open-source code of the OpenJDK to see what some smart people decided to do with this permission:

- [source code of compareAndSet](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.java#L113)
- [source code of weakCompareAndSet](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.java#L129)

Namely: They're both implemented as the one-liner

```
return unsafe.compareAndSwapObject(this, valueOffset, expect, update);
```

They have exactly the same performance, because *they have exactly the same implementation!* (in OpenJDK at least). Other people have remarked on the fact that you can't really do any better on x86 anyway, because the hardware already gives you a bunch of guarantees "for free". It's only on simpler architectures like ARM that you have to worry about it.

Comment: The methods are probably intrinsic so I'm not sure the code you see is the code that is run...