# CAS based algorithms - how threads sees latest values?

Tags: java, compare-and-swap

I recently came to know about `CAS - Compare and Set` and I tried to know more about it. I checked online in quest to know more and came across [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8XJ8r_n7POY) link.

How is it possible that without locking , using `CAS` threads can get / update values.

For example, in multicore processors they keep values in their own cache (and that is why we use `volatile` when we want threads to read latest values). So, even if, there is `CAS`, won't threads trying to do this operation be reading from their own cache?

Are these types of operations to be supported by Hardware?  Any inputs, as a novice how to get familiar with this?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183202/java-compare-and-swap-semantics-and-performance). Those operations add memory barriers +/- equivalent to `volatile`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Thanks for sharing the link. I am in incipient stage of understanding.  Assuming same code to executed by two different threads, how does it work? At least any one of the thread has to "wait" for a while? How is it possible that without any synchronization, they have recent updates? Could you elaborate a bit?