# using for(boolean haveNext = false;;) instead of while(cond)

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, concurrency

Here is a code snippet from `AtomicInteger`:

```
public final int accumulateAndGet(int x,
                                  IntBinaryOperator accumulatorFunction) {
    int prev = get(), next = 0;
    for (boolean haveNext = false;;) {
        if (!haveNext)
            next = accumulatorFunction.applyAsInt(prev, x);
        if (weakCompareAndSetVolatile(prev, next))
            return next;
        haveNext = (prev == (prev = get()));
    }
}
```

Is there any specific reason of using `for(...` instead of `while(...` or it's just a programming choice?

Is it because of the reordering done by the jvm?

Comment: This seems unnecessarily opaque.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I am sorry, I don't get it. Do you mean opaque memory mode?

Comment: The only difference vs a while loop here is that `haveNext` is scoped to the for loop. Since there's nothing following the for loop, that's not really an advantage.

Comment: I mean that the code is difficult to read without needing to be.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- so it doesn't have to do anything with the reordering, right?

Comment: @ConcurrentBhai nothing at all.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thank you andy

Comment: I don't see what "reordering" could be involved; by the time the JVM gets involved, this will have been reduced to equivalent bytecode.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Maybe I need to look into it again. Thank you for the help

Comment: That's typical Doug Lea / Martin Buchholz style (the JDK concurrency czars). Almost noone else has this coding style.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the loop is left in the middle, not at the start (then programmer could use "while"), or end  (then programmer could use "do ... while").
It is not connected with reordering.

Comment: What does "the loop is left" mean?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- 3 more words: "loop is left in the middle". He is talking about the `return` statement. "break" would be more specific word.

Comment: @ConcurrentBhai Exactly what I was getting at: An early return, since it exits the loop instantaneously and permanently, has nothing to do with the loop-type selection here.

Comment: Can you clarify this Alexei as chrylis comment seems legit.

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR.: This is done to prevent an unnecessary remapping of `next`.**

This is because of the "weak" nature of the weakCompareAndSetVolatile:

```
/**
 * Possibly atomically sets the value to {@code newValue}
 * if the current value {@code == expectedValue},
 * with memory effects as specified by
 * {@link VarHandle#weakCompareAndSet}.
 *
 * @param expectedValue the expected value
 * @param newValue the new value
 * @return {@code true} if successful
 * @since 9
 */
public final boolean weakCompareAndSetVolatile(V expectedValue, V newValue) {
    return VALUE.weakCompareAndSet(this, expectedValue, newValue);
}
```

**On the "weak" nature of the weakCompareAndSet's:**

"... [But on other platforms such as PowerPC or ARM (without LSE extension) CAS is implemented as a sequence of several instructions which provide LL/SC behavior and memory barriers as separate building blocks. This creates some wiggle room how strong your CAS can be both in terms of ordering and failure guarantees.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36429945/11214643)"

What the Javadoc defines as "[May fail spuriously.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/355374/11214643)"

Because of the possibility of these **false negatives**, the line `haveNext = (prev == (prev = get()));` needs to reassure that the CAS failed because of a true miss (a change in the volatile value), and not because it *"failed spuriously"*.

In reality, this would not be needed if the function `accumulatorFunction.applyAsInt(prev, x);` would not be required to redefine `next` each time `prev` received a volatile write, hence changing its value... **on each loop**, meaning the reason for this double check **is to prevent an unnecessary remapping of `next`.**

At first glance it seems as if a mismatched version of `next` could happen in between loops (when a wrong version of `prev` passes the function), and that is correct. BUT the mismatched version **will never be set** because by the time the loop reaches the `weakCompareAndSetVolatile`, the expected value will not match, and so the entire process will retry, until everything matches.

Answer (score 0):

In that specific use case for AtomicInteger the variable can be defined within the scope of usage once where as with a while-loop it would be defined out-side of the scope of the iteration. I would assume that played into the choice of iteration mechanism.

Comment: "it would be constantly redefined upon each iteration." only if you put it inside the loop.

Comment: @AndyTurner yeah so I should have specifically indicated that the purpose would be to keep it to the scope of the block its defined in instead of created outside of the scope.

Comment: @ConcurrentBhai Yeah you're right that is a really good point that I overlooked. I shouldn't have rushed to answer.